# Should functions not be the parameter?

Tags: function, syntax, f#, parameters

```
let sub (a:float[]) (b:float[])=  
    [| for i = 0 to Array.length a - 1 do yield a.[i]-b.[i] |]

let fx t = [0..t]
let x=sub (fx t) (fx t)
```

Above compiles OK.

But the same causes an error when I replace the function call with a method invocation:

```
type type_f = delegate of float -> float[]
let mutable f =new type_f(fun t->[|0..t|])
let m=f.Invoke(5) //float[]
let y=sub m f.Invoke(5)//error
```

How do I pass the result of a method invocation as a parameter to a function?

Comment: Not to be nasty but considering that you've just posted 3 questions all regarding one small snippet of code perhaps you'd benefit by taking some time to read the F# wikibook or some other book on basic F# syntax.  Possibly you want to study the language syntax a little more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In F#, the line

```
let y = sub m f.Invoke(5)
```

ambiguously parses as

```
let y = sub   m   f.Invoke   (5)
```

(passing three arguments to `sub`).

To fix this, you need more parentheses:

```
let y = sub m (f.Invoke(5))
```

(Note that using `delegate` types is not idiomatic unless interoperating with .NET code in other languages.  If `f` was a function, then

```
let y = sub m (f 5)
```

would be sufficient, as you have noted.)